# left join in hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, left-join

would anyone kindly answer the question below?

Is left join outer join or inner join in hive?

(Do we need to type left **"outer"** join in order to do the outer join? or simply **left join** works as outer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in most, if not all, databases, the `outer` word is optional in `left [outer] join`, while both syntaxs have the exact same meaning.

A quick glance at [the hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins):

> Hive supports the following syntax for joining tables:
>
> ```
> join_table:
>     table_reference [INNER] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]   
>   | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT|FULL} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition   
>   | table_reference LEFT SEMI JOIN table_reference join_condition   
>   | table_reference CROSS JOIN table_reference [join_condition] (as of Hive 0.10)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent in (almost) all databases:

- `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN`
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`
- `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`
- `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `FULL JOIN`